# Detecting array indexing in llvm IR

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

My task is to detect things like:

```
array[i][j][k];
```

And insert the next function before them:

```
instrument_array_indexing(array, i, j, k);
```

My first thought was to write a clang-pass which would find all getelementptr and check if its base address parametr has array type. The problem is that works only for static arrays, not for dynamic ones. Maybe there's another way to do it? For example, write clang AST matcher etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: That'll work for dynamic arrays too. Just go ahead and do it, you'll learn some details while writing the code and eventually it'll work.

Comment: @arnt Thanks for you comment, but I am sure it will not works with dynamic arrays. Base addres type in `getelemetptr` instruction is defferent for dynamic and static arrays. For static ones it's ArrayTypePtr, and for dynamic ones it is just `ptr`.

Comment: Detect array indexing? As opposed to pointer indexing? Or detect memory load?

Comment: You're quite right that the pointer argument contains insufficient information for it to work. However, a GEP [has more arguments](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html#a9546224d23202b1f091c581bbeee64e8), not just that pointer. Pay particular attention to the one called PointeeType.

Comment: @NickLewycky I want to insesrt my function call (I mean, instrument_array_indexing function) after each line of code where indexing is presented. Things like array[i] = 0; or new_var = array[i], or function(array[i]); etc.

Comment: @arnt I am tolking about llvm ir gep instruction. And now I am almost sure there's no way to detect if gep is used for array or for something else. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: An LLVM IR GEP instruction is created by calling one of the constructors of the GetElementPtrInst class, such as the constructor to which I linked. The instruction works by looking at the sizes of the element types of the supplied pointee type, computing an offset and adding that to the supplied pointer. It works for any kind of array, because all array types afford computing an offset into the array.

Comment: @DKay Is `&array[1]` indexing? Is `ptr[1]` indexing? Is `"abc"[1]` indexing? Is `sizeof(array[1])` indexing? Is `array+sizeof(array[0])` indexing? Is `array[1] = 'b';` indexing? Is `1[array]` indexing? LLVM does constant folding so "abc"[1] is likely gone, though that can vary. sizeof() is evaluated on the frontend and LLVM never sees the expression inside. When compiled by clang, `void f() { int x[7];` produces LLVM IR with an ArrayType, but `void f(int x[7]) {` produces LLVM that is precisely the same as `void (int *x) {`.

Comment: @NickLewycky Well, I need to instrument at least something of this. I believe there's a way to add annotations / debug info to clang AST nodes "ArraySubscriptExpr", to find them from IR.